# Else if function in Mysql, Get the 42000 Error

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am trying different ways to make an else if function in Mysql database but always I get different Errors, for example for the following code:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE NameSurname(IN mynumber INT, OUT status varchar(50))
BEGIN
IF mynumber = 1 THEN
  SET status = 'Yusuf';
ELSEIF mynumber = 2 THEN
  SET status = 'SEZER';
ELSEIF mynumber = 3 THEN
  SET status = 'Yusuf SEZER';
ELSE
  SET status = 'Yusuf Sefa SEZER';
END IF;
END//
DELIMITER ;


SET @result= 0;
CALL NameSurname(99, @result);
SELECT @result;
```

I get the following error:
SQL Error [1305] [42000]: PROCEDURE database.NameSurname does not exist

how can i solve my problem?

Comment: I can't reproduce the error.

Comment: If there's a problem defining the procedure, you should have gotten an error after typing `END//`.

Comment: @Barmar I have tried many ways but it seems just I am having this error not others.

Comment: I copied your exact code into the `mysql` command-line client, it worked fine.

Comment: I cannot stil understand what is the problem why after creation of the table again it does not exist... could it be because of DB or should I do some changes in it?

Comment: If we can't reproduce the problem, it's hard to solve it.